# CAShapeLayer draw dotted line only in Bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cashapelayer

Hello Guys i have been trying to Draw the Dotted line below `UILabel` using this code

```
extension UIView{

    func addDashedBorder() {

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            let color = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor

            let shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let frameSize = self.frame.size
            let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: 0)

            shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
            shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height)
            shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.50
            shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound

            shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [3,2]
            shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, shapeRect.height, shapeRect.width, 0), cornerRadius: 0).CGPath

            self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    }

}
```

So here i have been trying to create the **extension** so i can utilize it to every where in my code. but this doesn't give me the perfect result some time.

[image]

sometimes this code failed just check the **Gender** and **Birth date** in both the label i have used the same code but not getting the expected result, Any suggestion ?

Comment: Birth date looks fine ?

Comment: Where are you calling add dashed border ? I suggest you make the dashedLayer a property and try removing and adding it in willDisplayCell. It could be that cell recycling is screwing up the layer.

Comment: @SamhanSalahuddin yes Birthdate Looks fine and Its a Static Tableview so not using the Cell For Row at indexpath